# How to fix the "Invalid Provisioning Profile" when uploading to AppStore through Azure Devops Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, azure-devops, fastlane, azure-devops-extensions

I'm implementing continuous integration using Azure Devops and fastlane for an iOS app. It build and create the IPA file, however, when I try to upload the file after successfully creating the package I get this error
message: "Invalid Provisioning Profile". This is the only distribution profile used in the app and it's working fine with Xcode, so it's valid. How to fix it?

- Change the code signing identity to automatic and manual, in both project and target.
  -Using manual sign in. It's currently in automatic mode.
- Provisioning profile on build settings inside Xcode, currently in automatic, was changed to Manual and set as 5c0e9419-2a5a-4905-ac99-e680efac07a5. I changed back to automatic.
- Used only the distribution certificate on the Xcode build. When I try that, there's an error in the build saying it can't find an iOS Development provisioning profile. I'm currently installing both development and distribution certificates on the pipeline build.

**Here's is how I setup Azure Devops (Build Pipeline).**

```
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'iOSDistributionCertificate.p12'
    certPwd: 'xxxxx'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'iOSDevelopmentCertificate.p12'
    certPwd: 'xxxxx'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: '5c0e9419-2a5a-4905-ac99-e680efac07a5.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: '4e932719-f9bd-4d3e-b4e6-08b35260c632.mobileprovision'

- task: ios-bundle-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'BookingApp/info.plist'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionCodeOffset: '0'
    printFile: true

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build the app using Xcode'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'iphoneos12.4'
    configuration: 'Release'
    scheme: 'BookingApp'
    packageApp: true
    xcodeVersion: 10 # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'auto'
    useXcpretty: false # Makes it easier to diagnose build failures
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'

- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'Booking App Connection'
    appType: 'iOS'
    ipaPath: '**/*.ipa'
    releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
    installFastlane: false
```

**And here's the error message.**

```
[17:02:55]: ‌Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https:&#x2F;&#x2F;docs.fastlane.tools&#x2F;getting-started&#x2F;ios&#x2F;setup&#x2F;#use-a-gemfile‌
[17:02:56]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[17:02:56]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[17:02:56]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[17:02:56]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[17:02:56]: Login to App Store Connect (***)
[17:03:13]: Login successful
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:44: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
[17:03:16]: Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 1483789798)...
[17:03:16]: Fetching password for transporter from environment variable named `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`
[17:03:16]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[17:03:16]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[17:04:09]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
[17:04:09]: Transporter transfer failed.
[17:04:09]: 
[17:04:09]: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal.

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter]  (1102)

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication. 

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] 1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter]   /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/d20191016-2378-s6wyrx/1483789798.itmsp - Error Messages:

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter]       ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

[17:04:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-16 17:04:09 UTC] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1

[17:04:09]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
[17:04:09]: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BAG.BookingAppTests [Payload/BookingApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me several times until I decide to create again the profiles and make some changes in my yml file. Here is a full working pipeline:

```
# Xcode
# Build, test, and archive an Xcode workspace on macOS.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode
# Production
# Note: The certificates annd provisioning profiles path/passwors are stored in Group Variables

trigger:
 - master   

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.14'

variables:
  - group: 'Distribution Demo iOS'
  - name: BuildConfiguration
    value: 'Dev Release'
  - name: XCWorkSpacePath 
    value: 'CLI.xcworkspace'
  - name: Scheme 
    value: 'CLI'
  - name: ExportPath
    value: 'build'
  - name: ExportOptionsPListPath 
    value: 'exportOptions.plist'
  - name: AppIdentifier 
    value: 'cli.dev.test.CLI'
  - name: sdk 
    value: 'iphoneos'

steps:

- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'Downloading dependencies using CocoaPods with a forced repo update'
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: true 

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Installing Apple Certificates from Secure Files'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: $(CertificateFileName)
    certPwd: $(CertificatePassword)

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Installing Apple Provisioning Profile from Secure Files'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: secureFiles
    provProfileSecureFile: $(ProvisioningFileName)
    removeProfile: false 

# Uncomment the next lines if you want to the current build manages the next version
#- task: Bash@3
#  displayName: 'Updating Build Number to the Next Version'
#  inputs:
#    targetType: inline
#    script: 'xcrun agvtool next-version -all'

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Archiving Application and Save In Build Path' 
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
    xcWorkspacePath: $(XCWorkSpacePath)
    scheme: $(Scheme)
    packageApp: true 
    archivePath: $(ExportPath)
    exportPath: $(ExportPath)
    exportOptions: plist
    exportOptionsPlist: $(ExportOptionsPListPath)
    signingOption: manual
    provisioningProfileUuid: $(ProvisioningProfileUUID)
    provisioningProfileName: $(ProvisioningProfileName)

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copying IPA to Artifacts Directory'
  inputs:
    Contents: '$(ExportPath)/*.ipa'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Uploading IPA for the Currenet Run'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'GeneratedIPA'
    PublishLocation: Container

- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  displayName: 'Releasing IPA to TestFlight'
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'Apple2'
    appIdentifier: $(AppIdentifier)
    appType: iOS
    ipaPath: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa'
    releaseTrack: TestFlight
    releaseNotes: 'testflight.developer_notes.txt'
    shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: false 
    shouldSkipSubmission: false 
    # If you want to distribute to external testers uncomment the next two variables and write the group in externalTestersGroups
    # distributedToExternalTesters: true 
    # externalTestersGroups: 'groups'
    teamId: $(TeamID)
    teamName: $(TeamName)
    fastlaneArguments: 'action increment_build_number'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's what I did so far: 1. Deleted the old certificates on the Provisioning folder. 2. Created a new provisioning profile on the Apple website, downloaded and added to my project. 3- Changed the configuration of my xcode project to Manual. 4- Selected Code Signing Identify on target as follow - Debug: iOS Developer. Release: iOS Distribution. Provisioning Profile: Selected manually.However, I get an error while building: error: requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.

Comment: Which provisioning profile and certificates did you use on your code, the dev (iOS Development) or production (iOS Distribution), and which method did you use to export them?

Comment: Hello, I used iOS Distribution. Be sure that you're pushing to the correct branch.

Comment: Hey, I managed to make it works. However, I created the provisioning profile using fastlane, and uploaded to Azure only this one. After running a couple of times, fastlane started requiring the SMS code even despite I added the FASTLANE_SESSION that I got via fastlane spaceauth. Error message: Login to App Store Connect (***)
Session loaded from environment variable is not valid. Continuing with normal login.
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account '***'
(Input `sms` to escape this prompt and select a trusted phone number... ). Have you had this error?

Comment: Yes, you need to create application password. Check this link https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/ or maybe disable two factor authentication but I don't recommend this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's what I did and worked for the first time. Now it's asking the SMS code again, even with application password, regular apple password and email, and the fastlane_session code. Maybe it's a bug from Apple or Fastlane.